How do I build an Observable like this?
I have a backend service from which I can retrieve a series of data entries (let's say, of type DataEntry). Each entry has a flag isCompleted, which if set to false, means there are more entries to come; otherwise it will be the last entry to emit.
On the frontend I would like to build a service, which provides a method getLatestEntry$() => Observable<DataEntry> that when called:

Request one DataEntry from the backend, and return as an observable;
If a request is in progress, return a shared observable that represents the current request;
If a retrieved DataEntry is isCompleted === false, the next call to this method should request from the backend again (repeat step 1).
If a retrieved DataEntry is isCompleted === true, the upcoming calls to this method will not invoke the backend any more. Instead, the latest DataEntry will be wrapped in an observable and returned.

In other words, the frontend service should cache a completed entry; if no completed entry was emitted, it should retrieve the latest entry from the backend (as a cold observable) when requested; it should also guarantee that an ongoing request should be shared amongst the callers.
Is it possible to achieve this solely by using an rxjs pipeline?

The operator you're looking for is expand
